# Geography Types & SQL Server - Inside Shape?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coordinates, geography

I have a collection of lat/long pairs that specify the coordinates of property. An example of such would be this:

(-97.7157864909875 30.406523562241, -97.7165355983733 30.4068866164923, -97.716787930159 30.4064954568619, -97.7168253595963 30.4065335493939, -97.7168568837126 30.4065754656014, -97.7168819885038 30.4066205220471, -97.716901410079 30.4066619534041, -97.7169158736828 30.4066896672646, -97.7169327718411 30.4067163205123, -97.716952004751 30.4067417571518, -97.7169734604111 30.4067658281043, -97.7176225812739 30.4057595267431, -97.7168902352123 30.4054046115321, -97.7164489526149 30.4060840883432, -97.7163106372336 30.4061380633337, -97.7158545237879 30.4059170368804, -97.7158294889129 30.4060371739058, -97.7158101406138 30.4061580975546, -97.7157965112558 30.4062796056817, -97.7157886236446 30.4064014951642, -97.7157864909875 30.406523562241)

Lets say I have maybe 30K or so of these in a table.

Then I have a single lat/lon pair and I need to know which of the polygons (could be more than one) does this point fall inside of.

I have very limited experience with spatial types and I am trying ensure I can properly define indexes on this to gain the speed I need with this query.

Any help you can offer to get me headed in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

I believe I can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentPosition geography
declare @Line geography
DECLARE @result geography

SET @CurrentPosition = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(lat lon)', 4326)
set @Line = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(point collection)', 4326)
SELECT @result = @Line.STIntersection(@CurrentPosition)
select @result.ToString()
```

This will help with the actual is it inside the line or not - but the question I am struggling with is how to define the selection statement to perform the above transaction when I am searching the table for the items that intersect.

Thanks

Comment: I am new to Stack here - how can I get more traction on a question?